# Why is Logstash importing the same file every time I restart it?

Tags: logstash, kibana

Why does logstash import the same file everytime I restart it?

I have 3 different log files within the same folder *(C:/temp/ in this example)*. Everytime I restart logstash, the files are being imported again! Is this expected?

**logstash.conf**

```
input { 
  file { 
    type => "app" 
    path => [ "C:/temp/*.log" ] 
    codec => "json" 
  }
}

output { 
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

This is the command which I use to run logstash (I'm using Windows):

```
java -jar logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar agent -f logstash.conf -- web
```

I know the files are being imported everytime I restart because they are being output to the console and I can see the same log messages appearing several times when browsing the logs through kibana.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question:

In fact, this is not expected and it's a known bug for windows. You can check it here [here](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-429) and 
[here](https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-1587) (quote below).

> After several tests on Linux and Windows, I realized that if logstash
>   is (re-) started on Windows, all logs are parsed from the beginning
>   again. It does not matter if I set a start_position or an since_db
>   path, or an combination of both, the setting will be ignored.

**UPDATE**:

I fixed this by manually patching *logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar* with some changes made by edwinf to *ruby-filewatch*. In case you want to do the same:

1. Open https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/tree/master/lib/filewatch and download **buftok.rb, tail.rb, watch.rb and winhelper.rb**
2. Open logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar using any zip file editor and put the downloaded files inside the folder named "filewatch" (replace the original files)
3. Download **JRubyFileExtension.jar** from https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/tree/master/java
4. Put this file at the root of *logstash-1.3.3-flatjar.jar* (while opening it with a zip file editor).
5. Done. Logstash must be rerun, of course :)

The pull request which fixes this issue can be found at https://github.com/jordansissel/ruby-filewatch/pull/22